# How can a fighter jet pilot pour water from a bottle to a cup without spilling while doing barrel rolls?

Tags: aircraft

I came to watch two videos related to fighter jets, one in which the pilot pours red bull in a glass and another in which pilot pours water from a bottle to cup while doing rolls and while being upside down and not a drop of water got spilt. Here is the link of both the videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zG9Xsb0YPYg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g99ho_ExApU. How is this possible?

Comment: Lots of practice

Comment: @Dale But what's the physics behind it?

Comment: Have you ever ridden a loop-the-loop roller coaster?

Answer (score 1):

to execute a roll requires the airplane to rotate about its longitudinal axis. In a slow roll without a pull-up/pushover entry the roll axis is offset slightly from the plane's centerline so that when rolling the plane, the plane and its contents will experience an artificial G-force that points towards the roll center. This makes the liquid pour into the cup even when the plane is completely inverted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do a roll. It's based on the aircraft being trimmed for 1-G flight, which it normally is.

First you pull the nose up a bit.
Then you roll left or right, holding the 1-G trim (which takes no attention).
At the top of the roll (inverted) the wings are still generating 1-G.
It just happens to be downward.

Why don't you hit the ground?
Because you started by going upward, and the whole maneuver doesn't take very long.